# read_html malfunctions when used with parLapply R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, rvest

So I am trying to do web scraping of an API with millions of individual pages. To do so I am using parallel processing and the rvest package. The problem arises because the function read_html returns an empty xml document when used inside the cluster. Does anyone have a solution for this? So far I have been using getURL function but the problem is the size of the object increases  from one function to another and when talking tenths of millions of websites it makes quite a difference. My sample(toy) code that shows the problem  is:

```
library(parallel)
docss<-c('https://stackoverflow.com/' , 'https://stackoverflow.com/')

read_html(paste0(docss[1]))

cl<-makeCluster(2)

clusterEvalQ(cl, {require(rvest)})
clusterExport(cl,'docss')

dats<-parLapply(cl, docss, function(j){
read_html(paste0(docss[1]))
})

dats

stopCluster(cl)
```

This happens not only with the parLapply function but also with doParallel's foreach, and since I am working with Windows I cannot use many other options for parallel processing.

Comment: You aren't scraping StackOverflow. I'll gladly help if you provide the actual site you're trying to scrape. Otherwise I'll just assume you're a content thief and be on my way.

Comment: Thanks for your response @hrbrmstr. The site is the API of the "CMS National Plan and Provider Enumeration System", a publicly available source of data. Sorry for not including the whole code but it is easier to just copy this into R and replicate the same error. This happens with any site so this should not be a problem. [link](https://www.cms.gov/Research-Statistics-Data-and-Systems/Research-Statistics-Data-and-Systems.html)

Comment: Ah, cool. So `read_html` is C-backed & it returns an "external pointer" object. The authors of `xml2` chose to not provide an automatic serializer for those objects so you need to return actual HTML back via `as.character()`. I'd recommend using `httr::GET` in a try or tryCatch block so you can trap exceptions and test return status codes then return the HTML via `httr::content(result, as="text")`. That way you can retry operations. Also, please add a 5s [crawl delay](https://rud.is/b/2017/07/28/analyzing-wait-delay-settings-in-common-crawl-robots-txt-data-with-r/) to your iterations.

Comment: Thanks again. I implemented your solution and seems to be working just fine.